# Автозапуск .jar файла при его изменении на удаленном сервере Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar

В общем, на сервере должна выполняться программа - сервер на java для примитивного мессенджера. В среде разработки Intellij есть возможность при коммитах автоматически загружать и обновлять jar файл на сервере. Есть ли какая-нибудь возможность настроить его удаленный запуск и не подключаться к серверу через консоль по ssh. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Можно написать простой **bash** скрипт который билдит и запускает приложение на сервер сайде. Если ты используешь для сборки maven можно воспользаваться `exec-maven-plugin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, в Intellij IDEA есть функция добавления команды терминала для удаленного сервера, которая находится по пути File->Settings->Tools->Remote SSH External Tools, в которой можно прописать нужную команду. Насколько я понял, важно добавить удаленный сервер не через настройки проекта, а через File->Default settings->Build,..->Deployment, иначе в настройках команды не будет виден требуемый сервер.
[image]
Подробный ответ по ссылке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380496/deploy-debug-java-code-on-a-remote-server-using-intellij/42392922#42392922